# Swift 2.1: how to override touchesBegan & touchesMoved

Tags: ios, swift, overriding, superclass, touchesbegan

I'm having a really weird behaviour with those two functions, when I declare them like this:

```
override func touchesBegin(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
```

I get error message which says:

```
Method does not override any method from its superclass
```

However when I declare them like this:

```
func touchesBegin(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
```

I get error message which says:

```
Method 'touchesBegan(_:withEvent:)' with Objective-C selector 'touchesBegan:withEvent:' conflicts with method 'touchesBegan(_:withEvent:)' from superclass 'UIResponder' with the same Objective-C selector

Method 'touchesMoved(_:withEvent:)' with Objective-C selector 'touchesMoved:withEvent:' conflicts with method 'touchesMoved(_:withEvent:)' from superclass 'UIResponder' with the same Objective-C selector
```

So do I or don't I override the function from superclass?

Comment: Can you expand the `...` sections of your code.

Comment: Sorry, I meant fill in the signatures, eg touchesBegan(...

Comment: Try `override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the method signatures you are looking for are:

```
class XXX : UIResponder {

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    }

    override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<UITouch>?, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    }
}
```